# Falling blocks don't work for me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a fire ability for something I'm making that will summon falling fire blocks, and I'm having issues with the fire disapearing.

I'm using `/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:fire"},Time:1}` and it doesn't seem to work. It still disapears regarless of the `Time:1` tag.

I have used this method of spawning fire many times in the past, and it confuses me why it doesn't work anymore. I've checked for errors a fair amount of times and even loaded up old worlds (in 1.13) and copied the command (and while in 1.13 on the old worlds it worked but still doesn't work on new worlds).

Comment: It works for me. Of course only if the block it falls on it a block that fire can be at, so not if the falling block entity hits the corner of a block that is higher than the ground, because it would be placed in the air next to it, where it can't be. Can you check on flat ground again?

Comment: @FabianRöling I have been testing this on flat ground the entire time. It just disappears the moment I spawn it.

Comment: Not for me. With exactly that command.

Comment: It works for me too, is your world really lagy?

Comment: This might be redundant but try, `/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:fire"},Time:1,TileEntityData:{mode:"SAVE"}}`

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score -2):

Fire does not work with falling blocks I think it is a bug, try again with a different block like stone and see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with any block. I've tried stone, fire, sand, and a few others.

Comment: Fabian Röling and I have gotten it to work with fire. Doesn't seem to be a bug.

Answer (score -2):

This command is not working in command block. Because you used ~ ~ ~ in your command. While you must use ~ ~1 ~ in your command.

Comment: The only difference between ~ ~ ~ and ~ ~1~ is one block, why would that matter?

Comment: One block is important in command block. If you use ~ ~ ~, ~ ~ ~  will be summon falling block in command block.

Comment: Still, it sounds like he would have tried the commands without a command block. That would have worked.